# apache rewriterule overwriting url with similar name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The "morehere" rule below is getting skipped and is redirecting to the "more" rule. How can it be setup so that the "more" rule only directs the url /more and not /morehere

```
RewriteRule ^morehere /morehere.html [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^more /index#more [redirect=permanent,last,noescape]
```

***Edit**

I really don't need the "morehere" rule. Just a way to create a rewrite that goes to an anchor, that doesn't interfere with other pages if the rewrite word is contained within the other page name.

Answer (score 0):

The first rule is a terminal rule and will end in a fresh request which matches your second rule. Prefix the second rule with a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^morehere\.html
```

Comment: This forces the .html on the url but the real problem is that any url that contains more is directing traffic to the "more" rewrite. Is there a way to limit the "more" rule so that it only rewrites urls that are a direct match to /more and not /morestuff ?